# Python PyQt5 executable app wont update the sqlite db when closing the app

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, pyinstaller, executable

I have created an desktop app with Python and PyQt5 and sqlite database then create an .exe with Pyinstaller.

The app work completly fine and the database tables updates succefuly, but when closing the app and reopen the .exe file looks like the database tables empty.

any answers please.

Comment: link to the app in git https://github.com/otmanLAHRECHE/EPSP_Garde_Progect.git

Comment: Sorry, but questions should always be self-contained, and not rely on external resources that may become unavailable and thus make the question invalid. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. thanks musicamante
I was binding my sqlite database like the other resources (src files)
--add-data="database\db.db;database"
but when i added it like an external resource to the executable file, it work perfectlly.